# Term for Voronoi diagrams with non-point sites

Tags: geometry, terminology

I am looking for a term used to describe an analog to Voronoi diagrams where instead of a single point defining a cell, a continuous set of points is used.  For example, starting with five triangles on the plane, you could construct a diagram that contained regions where each point in that region would be closer to a certain triangle than any other triangle.

Is anyone aware of any papers dealing with this type of construction?  I'm having a hard time searching for any since I don't know if there is a name for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one reference, to the [CGAL manual section](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.1/doc_html/cgal_manual/Segment_Voronoi_diagram_2/Chapter_main.html) explaining its computation
of the Voronoi diagram of segments, e.g.:

[image: SegVorDiag]

Answer (score 4):

It's still called a Voronoi diagram.

Answer (score 1):

[The original paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=10549) for [Fortune's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm) for constructing Voronoi diagrams deals with the case of line segment sites (Section 3).